# Setting date format in unattended Windows deployment

Tags: windows-7, deployment, sccm, unattended

Our organization would like to use the ISO date format (known in Windows as yyyy-MM-dd).

I've configured this in our image.  When I deploy the image, it replaces the date format with the default for the locale in unattend.xml.  As far as I could see in the [Unattended Windows Setup Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699026.aspx) for Windows 7, there are no date format settings.

It can be done with a user logon script, or a user GPO, but I really need it to be included in deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I was the guy who suggested using GPO on Superuser for an almost identical question.  You can do what you are asking using the Components->Microsoft-International-Core->UserLocale settings assuming you are applying a user locale that has the settings you require.  I suspect you will already know this info.  So that might be the quickest way using the unattended setup.  There is also a SystemLocale under Microsoft-International-Core-WinPE as well that might work better.

I pulled the above info from Microsoft at :http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699026.aspx

Comment: What UserLocale uses the ISO date format?  Neither en-US or en-CA does.  GPO is out of the question because we need to remain having users able to change it.

Comment: There are many countries that use that format.  Here is one list available via Wikipedia.  If it isn't your local format, what is the point of changing it?  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

FWIW, you could apply the GP to the new computers OU and then simply move the computers out of that OU before you deploy them to the users.  If there isn't another GP to override it the setting should stick.

Comment: You're right, I wouldn't want to change my locale to something it's not.  I thought perhaps there were hidden locales like en-CA-ISO.  You'll note that many countries, like Canada, have more than one date format.  Microsoft has even changed what the default is for Canada between versions of Windows.

Comment: are you just trying to change the clock display?  The date and times are stored as a value and just show depending on what the user has selected.

Have you tried "ENC"?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx  Seems to indicate that is the ISO for en-CA.  Might be worth a shot...

Comment: No, not the clock display, the date format for the entire system.  ENC is an ISO 639 code for the name of a language.  This is unrelated to the ISO 8601 date format.

Comment: I am out of ideas,  perhaps the other answer might lead to something?  Just curious what you are trying to "fix" by changing this.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft lets you create [custom locales](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317785.aspx).  They offer a tool for this called **Microsoft Locale Builder**.

Version 1.0 is for Windows Vista and is no longer available from Microsoft, but can be [downloaded elsewhere](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Authoring-Related/Microsoft-Locale-Builder.shtml).

[Version 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=41158) is for Windows 8.1.

Neither version will install on Windows 7.  Bewildering--yes.